# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1:3

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building a quiz app for pharmacists like me to prepare for professional exams. My app isn't returning any error but I'm surprised at the error on my emulator.

Here's my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/question.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = ['What is your fav color?', 'What is your fav animal?'];

    var _questionIndex = 0;

    void _answerQuestion() {
      setState(() {
        _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
      });
      print(_questionIndex);
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Quiz App"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(_questionIndex + 1, questions[_questionIndex]),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
            Answer(_answerQuestion),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my `answer.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  //const Answer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my `question.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final questionNumber;
  final questionText;

  // Question(String question, {Key? key, required this.questionText})
  //     : super(key: key);

  Question(this.questionNumber, this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(
        '${questionNumber.toString()}. $questionText',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the error on my emulator:

[image]

Comment: why you are calling `setState` during buildTime? we cant call `setState` while `State isnot ready`.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1:3
```

telling that you have a List with size of 2, which is in range of `0..1`. But then you're trying to access item with index 3 which is not exist on your list. Hence the error generated.

The source of the problem is ,you only have two questions in your list variable:

```
var questions = ['What is your fav color?', 'What is your fav animal?'];
```

so it is within `0..1` range inclusively.

You're trying to increment the question index with the following code:

```
void _answerQuestion() {
  setState(() {
    _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
  });
  print(_questionIndex);
}
```

which will go beyond range of `0..1` of your `questions`.

To solve the problem, you need to restrict the maximum `questionIndex` to your `questions` length. Something like this:

```
void _answerQuestion() {
  setState(() {
    if(_questionIndex == questions.length - 1) {
      questionIndex = 0; // start again from zero.
    } else {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    }
  });
  print(_questionIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But then it returned a new error: Exception caught by widgets library 
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Answer
lib/main.dart:48  Exception caught by rendering library 
A RenderFlex overflowed by 299595 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib/main.dart:43

Comment: That's related to the child of `Column`. Try to wrap each child inside an `Expanded`. Something like `Expanded(child: Answer(_answerQuestion))`. Usually, the error log will give you a hint for the fix. Try the hint on the error log.

Comment: Please mark as an accepted answer if my answer solve your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, the culprit is at the _MyAppState, the first item in the column, `Question(_questionIndex + 1, questions[_questionIndex]),` replace it with `Question(_questionIndex, questions[_questionIndex]),`.

Another thing I noticed which may eventually lead to an unexpected behaviour is how you declared a field whose state you wish to update in the build method. To resolve this try moving the lines just before the return statement in the build method (main.dart) of the MyAppState outside the build method, like so:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


List<String> questions = ['What is your fav color?', 'What is your fav animal?'];

int _questionIndex = 0;

void _answerQuestion() {
  setState(() {
    _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
  });
  print(_questionIndex);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Quiz App"),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Question(_questionIndex, questions[_questionIndex]),
        Answer(_answerQuestion),
        Answer(_answerQuestion),
        Answer(_answerQuestion),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

Now another thing that contributed to the error is the fact that the number of questions in the `questions` list is two, so you should add a check at the point where you are adding 1 to the value of `_questionIndex` in the **`_answerQuestion()`** method, like so:

```
void _answerQuestion() {
  final newIndex = _questionIndex + 1;

  // This will make sure the [_questionIndex] does not exceed the available range.
  if (newIndex < questions.length) {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }

  print(_questionIndex);
}
```